# Match (formal and actual) type tokens programmatically

Tags: java, generics, reflection

In Guava, there is a way to programmatically replace formal type parameters by actual ones: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeResolver.html . To kind of reverse this, I want to find out how to programmatically match several given types:

```
TypeToken<?>
        t1 = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {},
        t2 = new TypeToken<List<?>>() {},
        t3 = new TypeToken<List<? extends Number>>() {},
        t4 = new TypeToken<L>() {},
        t5 = new TypeToken<Map<?, ?>>(){},
        t6 = new TypeToken<Map<?, String>>() {},
        t7 = new TypeToken<Integer>(){};

match(t1, t3); // returns null
match(t2, t1); // returns LinkedHashMap(WildcardType(?) => Class<String>)
match(t1, t2); // returns null
match(t4, t1); // returns LinkedHashMap(TypeVariable("L") => ParameterizedType(List<String>));
match(t5, t6); // returns LinkedHashMap(
               //   WildcardType(?) => WildcardType(?),
               //   WildcardType(?) => Class<String>
               // )
match(t4, t7); // returns LinkedHashMap(TypeVariable("L") => Class<Integer>);
```

It should at least return a map of formal type parameters to actual types, if types match, else `null`. An extension could match subclasses, too.
Is there a free implementation that solves this problem?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Can you point out the cases that are not covered but expected from the other implementation? The cases yet returning null are not unifiable, so there will not be an algorithm that returns a mapping for them.

Comment: @CoronA Instead of `null`, a blank map could be returned as well. Null means that the actual type (second) does not fit the definition (first).

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools. Or you could search for keywords like "type inference" or "unification".